# Does there exist an emacs intelligent parenthesis matching plugin/configuration?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs is there a mode where if I type ( it autocloses it like so (), but if I put it infront of a word like so (word it doesnt do ()word, but just intelligently stays like (word? I've tried smartparens and autopair to no avail, but maybe i haven't configured them correctly?

Comment: For coding, or for prose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built-in (as of version 24.something) `electric-pair-mode` with conservative pairing:

```
(setq-default electric-pair-inhibit-predicate 'electric-pair-conservative-inhibit)
(electric-pair-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

For programming, I find paredit to give me all I need.  It preserves balancedness.

Entering an opening parenthesis will also enter the closing one after points:

<kbd>(</kbd> → `()`

You can directly enclose the expression after point with a new pair of parenthesis:

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>(</kbd>  → `(expr)`

There are many other commands that slurp and barf sub-expressions to/from the front and rear, exchange expressions, moving on the different levels, etc., all preserving balancedness of parentheses.

For example, if you have some expressions (`|` denotes point):

```
|expr1 expr0 expr2 expr3
```

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>(</kbd>

```
(|expr1) expr0 expr2 expr3
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>)</kbd>

```
(|expr1 expr0) expr2 expr3
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>)</kbd>

```
(|expr1 expr0 expr2) expr3
```

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>

```
(expr1| expr0 expr2) expr3
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>

```
(expr0 expr1| expr2) expr3
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>{</kbd>

```
expr0 (expr1| expr2) expr3
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>

```
expr0 |(expr1 expr2) expr3
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>

```
expr0 (expr1 expr2) |expr3
```